# if else statement for css in html involving data retrieved from SQL

Tags: html, css, mysql

Hi so I am trying to use if else to change the colour displayed on the site, what I am trying to do is that when the order has been delivered it says 'delivered' in green and when it is pending/not delivered it is in red

context: deliveryStatus is the column name I have set in my order table in MYSQL workbench and there are 2 radio checkboxes in my add order form, delivered or pending.

addorder.handlebars

```
<div class="form-group mb-4">
    <label class="font-italic" for="status">Delivery Status</label>
    <br>
    <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
        <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="deliveryStatus" id="statusPending"
            value="Pending" onclick="ensureOneCheck('deliveryStatus', 'deliveryStatusErr', 'btnSubmit')">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="pending">Pending</label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
        <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="deliveryStatus" id="statusDelivered"
            value="Delivered" checked
            onclick="ensureOneCheck('deliveryStatus',   'deliveryStatusErr', 'btnSubmit')">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="delivered">Delivered</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

So this is what I have done in my handlebar to display the order and it showed an error when i try to do the if else statement like this

listorder.handlebars

```
{{ if {{deliveryStatus}} == "Delivered" }}
   <td class="align-middle" style="color: green;" >
      {{deliveryStatus}}
   </td>
{{else}}
   <td class="align-middle" style="color: red;" >
      {{deliveryStatus}}
   </td>
{{/if}}
```

and it showed this error

```
Error: Parse error on line 46:
... {{ if {{deliveryStatus}} =
-----------------------^
Expecting 'CLOSE_RAW_BLOCK', 'CLOSE', 'CLOSE_UNESCAPED', 'OPEN_SEXPR', 'CLOSE_SEXPR', 'ID', 'OPEN_BLOCK_PARAMS', 'STRING', 'NUMBER', 'BOOLEAN', 'UNDEFINED', 'NULL', 'DATA', 'SEP', got 'OPEN'
```

i have tried editing the if code to these 2 codes as well but both returned me an error message too

```
{{ #if {{deliveryStatus}} == "Delivered" }}
{{ if deliveryStatus = "Delivered" }}
```

All help is greatly appareciated !! I am unsure if just showing my codes like this would be sufficient or if I have to create an IDE or something, so do let me know !

Comment: Your question is really confusing to me. You start talkign about an if statement for CSS but have no CSS. Then you talk about parse errors while you not even mention with what you trying to aprse. What lirbary are you using? What has this question to do with CSS? what has this question to do with VSC? Also I see no relevance to mysql...

Comment: don't use `onClick` attribute of tags, connect a listener in your JS file.

Comment: @tacoshy i am using vsc for this project, the css is in the td code `style="color: red;"` as stated in my question for listorder.handlebars and i am retrieving my deliverystatus value from sql as stated in the context

Answer (score 0):

Don't add hard coded styles in your HTML.

Use something like

```
<td class="align-middle {{ if deliveryStatus == "Delivered" }}delivered{{else}}pending{{/if}}">
    {{deliveryStatus}}
</td>
```

And these CSS

```css
.delivered { color: green; }
.pending { color: red; }
```